# Magento backend shipping selection

Tags: php, magento

Heyhey,

I made a pretty kickass Magento 1.6 module to select a store and time to come pick stuff up at the shop, and it works fine in the front end. It doesn´t however appear in the backend, and the backend order creation system needs to have the same functionality.

How do I enable my module for backend order creation?
I'll supply any details needed!

Kind regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

in the file:
    /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml

around line 497 (on my version, which is Enterprise 1.10.0.1)

you should find

```
<adminhmtl_sales_order_create_index>
```

I strongly believe that has the information on what you want. Your module will need it's own layout xml file that references these areas to insert its own content. Then, you will need to hook into the order create event with an observer to run your own code to deal with the data. This may already be happening, as I'm not sure if the backend code creating the order is any different from the front end.

Hope this helps as a jumping off point.

Comment: please add backticks around the xml node, after "you should find"